# Frequency between intervals of events in a list

Tags: python, list, time, frequency

I have a list that records the occurrence of events:

```
a = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]
```

1 shows the occurrence of an event in a given timestep, and 0 is a timestep where the event hasn't been observed.

I am interested to estimate on python the stats of intervals between events. That is, the stats of the *times* I recorded no-events (the 0s): For example

```
- mean of interval of events: (2+4+3)/3 = 3
- max duration of an interval of no-event: 4
```

Any suggestions how should I do it?

Many thanks

Comment: so what have you tried? what are the problems you are encountering?

Comment: that I have no idea how to do it!

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities of combining the interval sequences, can you explain that? And do you have any idea regarding solving your problem (or any code that you've tried so far)?

Comment: In `(2+4+3)/3`, what does `2`, `4`, `3` represents. Count of `0`s excluding `0`s  at the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
interval_zeros = [len(list(group)) for z,group in itertools.groupby(data) if z== 0]
print sum(interval_zeros)/float(len(interval_zeros))
```

Comment: It would have been better if you would have just given the reference for `itertools.groupby()` and let the user implement the algorithm by his own

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of doing what you want. There are certainly more efficient ways of doing this, but this is simple:

```
a = [0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1]
a = map(str,a) # Convert numbers to strings
a = ''.join(a) # Concatenate all of the strings
a = a.split('1') # Use the handy split function to find the zeros
a = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, a) # select the zeros only
a = map(len,a) # convert zero sequences to lengths
print a
```

Here is the result

```
[2, 2, 4, 3]
```